# Why does the pointers cant pass the right values(C)?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I was given this task:

> Write a function that takes an array of integers "arr" and its size
> "n" and an integer "key" (It is known that the array has At least 2
> integers).

The function checks and returns 1 if there are two integers in an array whose sum is less than "key", otherwise the function
Returns 0. In addition if there are integers that satisfy this condition the function will pass their values ​​to "n" and "key", otherwise it will pass -1.

This is my solution:

```
int ex5(int* arr, int* n, int* key)
{
    while (*n > 0)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < *n - 1; i++)
        {
            if (arr[*n-1] + arr[i] < *key)
            {
                
                *n = arr[i];
                *key = arr[*n-1];*
                return 1;
            }
        }
        --*n;
    }
    *n = -1;
    *key = -1;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my main function:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 6, 2, 4, 3}, n = 5, key = 4;
    int res = ex5(arr, &n, &key);
    printf("%d %d %d", res, n, key);
}
```

However when i run my code the function returns me 1 and passes `(n = 1, key = 1)`, and it should pass `(n = 2, key = 1)`.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The whole thing would be a lot easier if you copied the values of `*n` and `*key` into local variables. Then write two nested `for` loops to find a pair of array elements that meet the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*n = arr[i]; 
*key = arr[*n-1];
```

The second line in above codes reads `arr[arr[i]-1];` This can be out of bound if for example `arr[i]` is 1000, and you only 5 elements in the array. There is no relation between the values in the array and  the array size. At least flip the order:

```
*key = arr[*n-1]; 
*n = arr[i];
```

You can also use two loops to make the code easier. Example

```
int ex5(int* arr, int *size, int *key)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++)
        for (int k = i + 1; k < *size; k++)
            if (arr[i] + arr[k] < *key)
            {
                *key = arr[i];
                *size = arr[k];
                return 1;
            }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write 2 for loops this would meet the condition.

```
int ex5(int* arr, int *size, int *key)
{
int i=0;
while(i<*size)
{
int k=i+1;
while(k<*size)
{
if (arr[i] + arr[k] < *key)
{
*key = arr[i];
*size = arr[k];
return 1;
}
i++;
}
return 0;
}
```